# Why are integrated circuits called "chips"?

Tags: etymology, nouns

Integrated circuits (IC) are called by many *chips*, and as a particular case, microprocessors are also nicknamed *chips*. The same happens in Hebrew, where ICs are called "shvav" (or "shvavim" in plural), which is the Hebrew word for a chip.

What is the source for the nickname?

Comment: I don't have enough detail for an answer, but I believe they got the name because the IC is etched onto a small piece, AKA a chip, of silicon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chip?region=uk&q=chip) says *chip* is short for *microchip.*

> Definition of **microchip**
>   *noun*
>     a tiny wafer of semiconducting material used to make an integrated circuit.

Thus *chip* has its normal meaning of ["a small piece"](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chip?region=uk&q=chip) (of silicon, in this case) and *microchip* is a tiny piece.

Even if the shortening of *microchip* is discounted, at the heart of each IC package is a tiny chip of silicon.

Comment: the chip is not the peace of silicon inside the package, it's in fact the IC itself, the chip is the full package with the IC, as can be seen in a description of a picture in the Wikipedia article for IC `Wide angle shot of the memory microchip shown in detail below. The microchips have a transparent window, showing the integrated circuit inside. The window allows the memory contents of the chip to be erased, by exposure to strong ultraviolet light in an eraser device.`

Comment: @IlyaMelamed Wikipedia is a convenient source of data, but without citations it's just opinion. What that caption calls a "microchip" is actually a **package**.

Comment: The citation is from me, I'm an Electrical engineer. A microchip is made from two different parts. The IC which is the electrical component "printed" on a semi conductor (most of the times, Si, but sometimes can be Ge, GaAs, C and other materials), and the package which is responsible for protection of the IC and for heat dissipation. A "chip" or a "microchip" is the whole component, IC and Package together.

Comment: I can see we're going to have to agree to disagree then. I have provided a citation, with which I happen to agree as it accords with my experience in the construction of electronic components. A slanging match gets everyone nowhere.

Comment: @AndewLeach, The source doesn't explain Why are ICs called "microchips", the explanation that chip is short for Microchip is reasonable and I think it's true, but it doesn't explain how did the name "Microchip" originated.

Comment: A chip is a small piece; a microchip is a really really small piece.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I agree with you (chip vs package) - after all, it's called a *silicon* chip but only the circuit is made of silicon. Note that [Chip-scale packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip-scale_package) exist which further highlight the distinction, and multi-chip modules. Colloquially, I'd say "please pass that chip" meaning the device as a whole, but then I'd say "please pass the bleach" and expect the bottle too. I don't think "microchip" is a real tech term; I can only remember hearing it in abstract, "microchip industry" - mostly to disambiguate from chips = potato products :-)

Comment: I beg to differ with Oxford's definition of microchip.
A microchip is not a tiny wafer but instead it is tiny piece of a wafer, a die.
Where a wafer is a slice from an ingot (Boule).

To the dilemma of is the microchip the package or the silicon (die) inside the package. I don't think there is a clear answer but if I had to choose one I would say the microchip is the final product, ie package. Which would then put me in disagreement with Oxford again.

PO\M